# android-How to make Staggered gridview like this

Tags: android, android-gridview

I've searched alot ,I've found libraries like AndroidStaggeredGrid , the problem is , all these libraries has different size of columns and they are not ordered well , as you can see on this image, each view has a diffrent size and not ordered in rows and columns very well 
[image]

I want something like image below :

[image]

as you can see, there is a big view but every row and columns are in order and in one line.

How can I make something similar ?

Comment: Have you tried [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) library ?

Comment: @YeLinAung Do youk now any library that I can use inside eclipse ?

Comment: Nope. Everyone's targeting and moving already to the Android Studio + Gradle. I think you should too :)